# Developing in Xcode with MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am new to Xcode and MonoTouch, so please bear with me.
Is it possible to develop MonoTouch applications with Xcode instead of with MonoDevelop? I have read the [MonoTouch Xcode](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/XCode) tutorial but unfortunately the process described does not seem to work with the latest MonoTouch version (I get a "No SDK in directory" error, there is also no resource rules file in the root SDK directory). Finally, where am I supposed to put the directives to the MonoTouch compiler?

I have downloaded the trial version of MonoTouch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That wiki page is horribly out of date, what are you trying to accomplish, why do you think you need Xcode?  MonoTouch+MonoDevelop provide and end to end solution to make apps ready for the app store.

Comment: It is one of the requirements of the project, that I do it in Xcode with Mono Touch. Otherwise I would be all over Mono Develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its technically possible, but not in the supported MonoTouch workflow, so you'd be somewhat on your own.  What you'd need to do is look at the output of a MonoTouch build with "-v -v -v" in the Extra Arguments field to see how we invoke the AOT compiler.  You'll also need to look at the main.m generated by -keeptemp and adapt that in to your Xcode workflow.  Lastly you would not be able to use the linker unless you maintained a parallel monotouch project which compiled and linked, and then you did a secondary build step to update your Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not support third-party plug-ins or environments.